# About the sentence "Do you have any idea"

Tags: grammaticality

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

> 1. Do you have any idea to prove it?
> 2. Do you have any idea how to prove it?
> 3. Do you have any idea about proving it?

Comment: When in doubt, simplify it! `Can you prove it?` :)

Comment: it looks impolite when you are talking to someone for first time.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *do you have any idea* can be roughly equivalent to *can you think of any way*:

> We locked our keys in the car! Do you have any idea how we can get in?

or sometimes its used for emphasis in an emotional question:

> You didn't come home until after 2 o'clock in the morning! Do you have any idea how worried we were?

So, more important than the grammatical correctness of your sentences, I think, is what are you trying to convey. Perhaps a team is trying to prove something that they believe is true, in which case I might say:

> I'm convinced that's true; do you have any idea how we might prove it?

Or maybe we are asking a rhetorical question, and we are using those words for emphasis. In that case, I might say something more like:

> Do you have any idea how hard that would be to prove?

If, on the other hand, we are unconvinced, and challenging someone's assertion about something, I think the *do you have any idea* construct would be an awkward fit. I'd probably say something more along the lines of:

> I'm not so sure that's always the case - can you prove it?

If you're worried about being impolite with a question, you could turn it into a statement:

> I think you might have trouble proving that.

Comment: A perfect answer, with plenty of examples. A lot of people have suggested "can you prove it?" as a simpler alternative to the OP's constructs, but I think this sounds far more aggressive in most situations. JR's examples above offer some more neutral, context-sensitive alternatives (with ***can you** prove it* being used when challenging somebody else's assertion).

Answer (score 2):

In practice, competent native speakers would probably never produce #1 or #3. And whereas there's nothing actually "wrong" with #2, it's very much an informal idiomatic usage.

It would be completely inappropriate in a project progress report, for example, to say *"The team don't have any idea when this project will be completed"*. Partly, obviously, because the team *should* know something like that, but mainly because *to have no idea about [something]* is far too informal. In OP's context, *"Do you know how to prove it?"* (or more succinctly, *"Can you prove it?"*) are more suitable.

In informal (primarily *spoken*) contexts, *[not] having an/any idea about something* usually carries strong implications, similar to *"I haven't a clue"*, or *"Don't ask me!"*. For example...

> *"Do you have any idea how much that cost?"*
>   would very often carry either or both the implications that the speaker believes (a) that the cost was [too] high, and (b) the other person should (but doesn't) know that. Correspondingly, the answer...
>
> *"I have no idea how much it cost"*
>   often implies the speaker thinks it *might* have been expensive, but doesn't really care about the cost.

Comment: by "idea" I mean the first meaning in http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/idea. A plan or a procedure of how to prove something that cannot be proved easily for example innocence of someone prisoned.

Comment: @CutieKrait: I knew what you meant by "idea". Note that it's irrelevant whether the thing you're asking for is a method of *proving* something difficult to establish conclusively, or of *overcoming/dealing with* some major problem *("Do you have any idea how to balance our budget?")*. The implications I mentioned are often present, and the usage itself is invariably highly informal, even when it doesn't carry critical overtones.

Comment: 'In practice, competent native speakers would probably never produce #1 or #3.'

Is #1 and #3 ungrammatical? Seems to me.

Comment: @XPMai: I don't think there are any useful grammatical rules relevant to this general area. Many people would probably say that #1 and #3 are indeed "ungrammatical", but actually they're just ***non-idiomatic*** (they don't "break" any defined grammatical rules; they're just not things native Anglophones say). One very important point that I don't seem to have raised above concerns the fact that we have a strong preference for ***singular*** in negating / belittling contexts ("You have **no idea** how much I hate you!"), but plural for advice ("I have **some ideas** that might help").

Answer (score 0):

Like @anderson commented, Use simple constructions when in doubt. Grammaticaly I see no problem in all the three sentences.

The first sentence is just another style of expressing the second sentence. Here *how* is implicit and in the second one *how* is explicit.

The third sentence is perfectly okay as well.

Comment: How about replacing "idea" with "ideas"?

Comment: @CutieKrait, As far as I know, any one of them is correct i.e. using singular or plural.

Comment: I had a different reaction on reading the first sentence; what I first thought (after thinking that some verb was missing) was not *how* to prove it, but whether one was even going to try.  Or, to paraphrase, "Do you have any thought that you might want to try to prove it?"  After reading the other two sentences, I realized that isn't what was meant, but if I read, or heard, the first sentence in isolation, I'm quite certain I would misunderstand.  So, even if it's strictly grammatical, it isn't clear.

Comment: I don't know, but frankly even before glancing on the second sentence I took _how_ to be implicit there.@barbarabeeton, however if you say so, it might be different people interpret it in different ways!