# 'Any' + plural nouns vs 'any' + singular nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Are both the following sentences correct?

1- Hi everyone, ask me ***any question***. I will answer it to the best of my ability.

2- Hi everyone, ask me ***any questions***. I will answer them to the best of my ability.

I think the second one using plural noun is correct. I am not sure.

Comment: My question is different. Could you please answer my question?

Comment: What you should do when someone proposes a duplicate is to read over the answers on the proposed duplicate, then if they don't help,
 [edit] your question to explain why those answers don't answer your question.

Comment: This question might have better answers for your question: [Should nouns after “any” be singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1155/)

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you. Question is a countable noun and that's why I think plural nouns should be used.

Comment: They are both fine. The "any" in your examples takes plural, non-count and count nouns. And they both have the same meaning, i.e. anyone can ask a question or questions.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of these two sentences is slightly different, and **you probably mean the plural version**.

In the plural version ("any question**s** [...] answer **them**"), the meaning is that there will be a period of questions-and-answers, for some amount of time and you will answer whatever you can. This is pretty common, so I suspect this is what you mean. If so, use this version.

In the singular version, the literal meaning is that you will allow one single question to be asked, and then you will answer that one single question. After that, you make no promises about answering more questions - and if this is really what you mean, then I'd expect that you would stop answering after the first. **This is an unusual thing to say**, so if this is what you mean (especially as a non-native speaker), you should emphasize the fact that you do mean a single question! e.g., if you said "ask me any *one* question [...]", with the verbal emphasis, it would be understood this way. Otherwise, people might think that you actually meant the plural version, and simply made a mistake.