# Any open position, positions, or either?

Tags: quantifiers, quantificational-nouns

Is the following question correct in an email?

> I am following up to inquire about any current open **positions** at the organization.

When a countable noun follows `any` in sentences without to-be verbs, are they in the plural or singular?

Comment: See the following article: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/should-nouns-after-any-be-singular-or-plural 

By the way, rather than saying "any current open positions", you could simply say "any vacancies", which sounds clearer and is more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article mentioned by the commenter:

> [Should nouns after "any" be singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/should-nouns-after-any-be-singular-or-plural)
>
> "If you have learnt a rule that "any" can only be connected with a singular noun it is wrong. "Any" can be used with singular or plural according to sense."

Then, to your example:

> I am following up to inquire about any current open positions at the organization.

Very good. The plural noun "positions" is preferable because it indicates flexibility, and openness to any positions they have.