# Singular nouns after 'any'

Tags: nouns, any

There have been similar questions on this site before, such as this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/should-nouns-after-any-be-singular-or-plural) but none of them seems to be able to give a definite answer on this one.

According to both [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/any_1) and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any?q=Any), when using in questions/negative setences, as in "Are there any people in the house?" or "There aren't any people in the house", we can only use plural or uncountable nouns. Below is the snapshot from the page of Cambridge Dictionary that explains it. Please note the yellow Warning box.

[image]

However, consider this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23618/should-i-write-any-question-or-any-questions) on English Stack Exchange where the OP asked which one is correct between "any questions?" and "any question?" and the accepted answer says both are correct and that ""Any question" places a strict limit on the number of questions allowable to exactly one."

For example, both of the following questions are correct:

- Is there any particular patient not responding to the prescribed medicine?
- Are there any particular patients not responding to the prescribed medicine?

While the first one implies the asker expects exactly one patient, the second one implies he expects more than one patients.

**So, who is correct between the dictionaries and the answer in the question?**

Comment: If someone on the linked question claimed that asking singular *"Any question?"* places a strict limit on the number of questions allowable to exactly one, they're talking rubbish. That's not an idiomatically valid thing to say. The singular occurs in many other context, such as *There is **no question** about it - "Any question?" is not a valid thing to say after, for example, delivering a talk*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you and I see. Can you provide a full answer to my question?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking here. Your final pair of "particular patient[s]" is a bit weird - I find it hard to imagine any speaker deliberately phrasing in the singular in order to indicate that he expects there to be at most one - but it's grammatically possible, obviously. The singular "Any question?" is just a mistake. I don't know if you're asking about singular/plural ***question[s]*** or the use of the word ***any.*** (Where I've no idea what you mean by "weak" ***any*** anyway! :)

Comment: ...but your lecturer would normally use singular ***Is** there **anyone** who didn't understand what I just said?* That certainly doesn't imply at most one person is "allowed" or expected to put their hand up! Note that you can't "pluralise" it without some rephrasing - for example, ***Are** there **any of you** who didn't understand?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Since you said that it is grammatically possible to say "is there any particular any patient", does it mean the page taken from the Cambridge dictionary in my question gives incorrect information? (Please pay attention to the yellow Warning box).

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. I can see that Cambridge distinguish "strong" and "weak" uses of ***any***, but at this stage in the game I don't know or care what that means. And I can't find the word ***patient*** on the relevant Cambridge definition page - but wherever you got that from, you obviously didn't "cut & paste" it, because you've ungrammatically included the word ***any*** twice.

Comment: btw - so far as I'm concerned, the first paragraph of the main answer on the linked ELU question is completely wrong. And the second paragraph doesn't really say much anyway, so I don't know why it's got so many upvotes. Ignore it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers basically, both Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries say we cannot use any + singular noun in questions and negative sentences. However, since you said that it's grammatically possible to say "is there any patient...?", it seems that it contradicts what the dictionaries dictate.

Comment: You keep making assertions that I don't think are true, but which you claim you're getting from those two dictionaries. If you give me some actual quoted text from either of your linked pages, I might be able to see exactly what you're misunderstanding. I *have* found ***any** - used with singular countable nouns to refer to one of a number of things or people, when it does not matter which one* in the oxford link, but that certainly doesn't imply plural *You can open **any books you like** in my bookcase, and you'll find my signature on the inside front cover* is in any way "defective".

Comment: When the plural has a different meaning than the singular (e.g. spectacle, wood, force) or when the noun is mostly used in the plural (i.e fog-lights, peanuts), plural following "any" is correct.

Comment: Could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired.

Comment: "we can only use plural or uncountable nouns in questions and negative sentences" I don't see where that is indicated in "the snapshot from the page of Cambridge Dictionary that explains it".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan In the beginning of the snapshot, right after the title, it says "We use 'any' for indefinite quantities in questions and negative sentences". And after the last example "Not: I've got any eggs", it says "We use weak form of 'any' only with uncountable nouns or plural nouns."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Here is the quote from the linked Cambridge dictionary page (It is in the beginning of the snapshot, right after the title): "We use 'any' for indefinite quantities in questions and negative sentences". And after the last example "Not: I've got any eggs", it says "We use weak form of 'any' only with uncountable nouns or plural nouns." Here, the weak form means using 'any' to describe indefinite quantities.

Comment: @ASlowLearner Right; it's talking about how to use "any", not how to use plural or uncountable nouns.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan and it says that when we use 'any' to talk about indefinite quantities (the 'weak' form), we do that only in questions/negative sentences, and with plural/uncountable nouns only.

Comment: @ASlowLearner Yes, "when we use 'any'", as you now say. However, your earlier sentence didn't say "when we use 'any'". Do you see why they're different? If not, then don't worry about it I guess because it's not worth belaboring the point, but you're definitely saying something different than Cambridge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147453/discussion-between-a-slow-learner-and-marcinmanhattan).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan oh I see. That's my bad. It should have had "when using any..." and I will correct it. But regarding what the Cambridge says and the rest of my question, which provides an exemple of using 'any' with singular nouns in questions/negative sentences, are there any contradictions between the dictionaries and the examples?

Answer (score 0):

#### Read the whole article. The answer is already there.

There are two forms of “any”: a weak and a strong. You have posted the definition for one (the “weak form”), but are confused when you see the other (the “strong form”).  But if you continue to read the rest of the articles you linked, you will find the answer is there.

- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/any

#### Your examples illustrate the two forms of “any”

Your two samples are an example of the strong and weak forms respectively:

- **strong**: Is there any particular patient not responding to the prescribed medicine?
- **weak**: Are there any particular patients not responding to the prescribed medicine?

Your interpretation, “*…the first one implies the asker expects exactly one patient, the second one implies he expects more than one patients.*” is right for the second case, but wrong for the first.

In the first, strong, sentence the speaker is asking about the existence of any patient, but they expect that there *isn’t* one, so they’re challenging the listener for a response. (“challenging” doesn’t mean they are being aggressive, just that by asking the question, they are making a claim).

In the second sentence, the use of the weak form, suggests that the speaker expects that there may be such patients, and is asking for confirmation. Here, the questioner makes no claims, and is just requesting information.

##### You should use relative clauses in questions like these

While it is possible to figure out your meaning here, the wording you have chosen is not natural. Instead of “not responding to...”, native speakers would use a [defining relative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining) here, as follows:

- Is there any particular patient **who does not respond** to the prescribed medicine?
- Are there any particular patients **who do not respond** to the prescribed medicine?

…note that “who” is the same for singular and plural subjects, but the verb “to respond” still has to change to match the subject.

##### “strong” and “weak” are spoken differently

The strong and weak forms are much easier to spot in speech:

- strong: Is there *a*ny patient not responding...?
- weak: Are there any *pat*ients not responding...?

Note that the “strong form” any is stressed, while the weak one has the word “any” unstressed.

#### This “rule” is general advice about the most common use of “any” to stop you making a common learner’s error

The weak form is the more common in writing and speech. The article is trying to steer you away from making clearly inocorrect statements like this:

- *wrong*:  Is there any chip in that packet?
- *wrong*:  I do not have any holiday left this year.
- *wrong*:  Is there any potato in the pantry?
- *wrong*:  We cannot sell any knife to you.

These are questions, or negative statements about quantity or number. In *this kind of sentence*, where there’s no emphasis, when you use “any `X`”, then the general rule is that `X` should be plural if it is a countable noun.

This is a good rule to learn first, but it is not by any means the only rule for the use of the word “any”, and your articles do go into several exceptions to this advice: just scroll down.

##### …some nouns look singular, but aren’t

Also, consider that there are nouns that are both countable and uncountable depending on the meaning:

1. *correct*: He doesn’t have **any heart**.

Why not “hearts?”. Well, it could be, if we were talking about a butcher, but here, “heart” is the uncountable noun meaning “compassion or kindness”, not the organ that pumps blood.

#### …but this does not apply to every kind of sentence with the word “any”

But this rule applies only to questions, or negative statements using what’s called the “weak” form of “any” - where you are not trying to claim anything by asking the question. The other form, the “strong form” is used to say you are not talking about the quantity, but about whether or not the thing exists. When you use the strong form, you are also making a statement about what you think the answer is (usually it’s “no”). Here are some examples:

1. *correct*: I don’t not know if he had **any home** in those days.
2. *correct*: **Any problem** that might occur would be minor.
3. *correct*: Is there **any among you** who would help me?

#3 is a different use of “any”, with the meaning of “any [person]”. It’s a little archaic, but because it is in English translations of the Christian Bible, and the works of Shakespeare, it still gets used sometimes by speechmakers (or dialogue for fantasy films...)

#### Other uses of “any”

These sentences are the “strong” form of any, but are not questions or negative statements, so there’s no special meaning if you use the singular or plural.

1. *correct*: You can have **any colour** you want.
2. *correct*: You can have **any colours** you want.
3. *correct*: “**Any port** in a storm”

Note #1 implies that the thing can be a single colour of your choice, #2 implies that one or more colours could be used.

#3 is a saying. The meaning is that when your situation is bad, you do not have the luxury of choosing who helps you: when the sea is stormy, even an unsafe port is a better place for your ship. This is a similar meaning to “beggars can’t be choosers” or the very idiomatic “needs must when the Devil drives”)

#### The strong form of “any” in questions and statements

Even in questions and negative statements, native speakers do indeed use singular nouns with “any”. Doing so is a sign that they’re using the strong form. Generally this is indicates:

- rhetorical questions
- very emphatic negative statements

1. Is there ***any* waiter** working in this restaurant tonight?
2. Is there ***any* reason** why I shouldn’t fire you right now?
3. There isn’t ***any* tire** for driving on ice (i.e., “such a thing does not exist”)
4. No, there isn’t ***any* ticket** (i.e., “you asked me for tickets to one show, there are in fact no tickets at all, regardless of the show”)

Remember that the strong form makes a claim as well as asking a question - the questions are basically re-phrasings of the emphatic “There *is* no `X`” (where “is” is stressed).  Also, note that this kind of strong emphatic or rhetorical use can seem impolite.

Comment: Isn't the sentence "is there any among you who would help me?" a question? But yoh listed it under "other kinds of sentence".

Comment: "Is there any among you who would help me?" is poor diction, this is not quite like "Is there any man among you who would help me?", because it is a different use of 'any'.  In the first sentence, 'any' functions as a pronoun, and not as a quantifier.

As I said in my answer, questions like "Is there any man among you who would help me?" and "Can there be any question?" are not an indefinitely quantity, so the OLD rule does not apply.  The use of 'any' as a quantifier is like the use of 'each' or 'every' as a quantifier:  "Every dog has his day."  The quantity is not indefinite; it is one.

Comment: @BadZen it’s not poor diction, it is, as I said, an archaic formulation, and you can find the construction in several current English translations of the Christian Bible (e.g, James 5:13; "Is any among you suffering? Let him pray. Is any cheerful?…" ).

Comment: There's no contest here, archaisms are a type of poor diction.

Comment: @BadZen Right-o. Archaic phrasing, such as that in the Bible or the works of Shakespeare has no place in “proper” English?  A bold assertion, and frankly a foolish hill to die on, but knock yourself out...

Comment: That's not at all what I said.  It is absolutely true archaisms are a type of poor diction.  Go find a typology of diction problems, and archaic use will be on it.   This is because what is considered "poor diction" changes over time and from dialect to dialect.   This is an English learning SE, and the author is asking about current use.   Giving them examples with archaic use is unhelpful.

Comment: I gave one single example of a construction that is often encountered, and I also made sure to point out that it was archaic. I think that's helpful to a learner: now they know first that this construction is used; second, that it is not an example of the “any [countable]” weak form; third, what it actually means; and fourth that they should avoid using it, because it is archaic.  “Learner” isn’t the same as “stupid”.

Comment: @KrisW in your answer, what is the difference between "I don’t know if he had any home in those days" and "I don't know if he had any homes in those days"; and similarly, between "any problem that might occur would be minor" and "any problems that might occur would be minor"?

Comment: @ASlowLearner - I advise you to read the article that you cut-and-pasted from fully: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/any   This will tell you that these are examples of the “strong form”, which means you are not talking about a quantity.  The “rule” of using plurals applies _only_ when using the “weak form”.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply - believe the Oxford Learner's Dictionary if it disagrees with anything you read here.

But - the OLD does not actually contradict FraserOrr's answer in the other ELL question you cite.

"Thanks for coming to my talk.  **Any question?**"

is incorrect use - this will sound wrong to nearly every fluent English speaker.  As the OLD rule indicates, we must not use a single form for an indefinite quantity with a countable noun.

"Thanks for coming to my talk.  **Can there be any question that this work is important?**

is *not* incorrect use, because *it is not an indefinite quantity*.   There is only one question here, even though its existence is hypothetical.  The rule you cite does not apply - notice the other asker simply asked if they should use "any question" or "any questions", without giving more information.

A good rule of thumb when using 'any' in the way OLD describes is simply to delete the word 'any' and see if the sentence still works.

So: "Is there potato in the pantry?" is incorrect, as "**Is there any potato in the pantry?" is also incorrect. And, "**Are there potatoes in the pantry?**" is good, just as "**Are there any potatoes in the pantry?**" is good.

Comment: I actually don't quite understand what the asker is asking in the question "Can there by any question that this work is important?". Can you explain to me?

Comment: The speaker is asking if a question about if the work is important or not can exist.   He is expecting a "no" answer, implying that it cannot exist and the work is important.   Another example is "Thanks for coming to my talk.  Any student who wishes to stay and discuss further, may".  This one is also not what the OLD is talking about - this time it is because it is not asking any question at all.   But it is still within the scope of the other ELL question.

Comment: Thank you. So, in your answer, when you say that saying "Is there any potato in the pantry?" is wrong, what if the reader is expecting a 'no' answer just like in the example "Can there by any question that this work is important?"

Comment: One would not say "Is there any potato in the pantry?".  The OLD rule applies - it is a question about an indefinite quantity.

Comment: I mean what if the asker is implying that there can only be one potato, if at all (perhaps he saw only one potato in the pantry the night before and this morning he wants to know if that potato is still there). In that case, can he use the singular form of the potato?

Comment: No, you cannot imply that there is at most one potato like this.  In the case that the speaker "saw only one potato in the pantry the night before and this morning he wants to know if that potato is still there", they might say: "is that potato in the pantry?"

Comment: A good rule of thumb when using 'any' in the way OLD describes is simply to delete the word 'any' and see if the sentence still works. So:  "Is there potato in the pantry" is incorrect, as "Is there any potato in the pantry?" is also incorrect.  And, "Are there potatoes in the pantry" is good, just as "Are there any potatoes in the pantry?" is good.

Comment: When applying the rule of thumb you say to the sentence "Can there be any question that this work is important?", I get "Can there be question that this work is important?", which doesn't sound correct to me (or am I being wrong?)

Comment: I gave you a "good rule of thumb when using 'any' in the way OLD describes". 

I also told you that "Can there be question that this work is important?" was /not/ the kind of sentence the OLD described, since the (quantity is not indefinite).  So, you shouldn't expect my "rule of thumb" to work there!  Right?  :)