Will you get _______ orange in the market?
This question is from an examination.
Fill in the blanks with an appropriate determiner:
Will you get ____ orange in the market?
a) any.
b) one.
c) some
d) many.
The normal way to ask this is:
Will you get some oranges from the market?
But the  noun "orange" is singular, so we can eliminate c) some and d) many
Which is the correct answer - a) any or b) one ? Explain why?
Edit-1.
OALD definition

Any
used with singular countable nouns to refer to one of a number of things or people, when it does not matter which one.
Take any book you like.
Any colour will do.
Any teacher will tell you that students learn at different rates.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/any_1


"Any" could be one or more and is treated as plural. And "no" as well: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Yes!_We_Have_No_Bananas

@DrMoishePippik It is a issue on which lots of debate goes on. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/should-nouns-after-any-be-singular-or-plural#:~:text=The%20sentences%20containing%20any%20ideas,for%20are%20dated%201995%2D1999.&text=If%20you%20have%20learnt%20a,or%20plural%20according%20to%20sense.

That is one very bad examination. How can that be so bad?

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a very bad example.

@Lambie In an examination, some questions are for A grade students. This question comes under this category.

@DrMoishePippik I believe there's an alternate interpretation possible here, which makes "any" a valid choice even though the noun is singular. When someone asks, "Would you get any [whatever item]," with emphasis on the word "any," the connotation is that they're asking whether you would be satisfied with an instance of [whatever item] regardless of quality/any other secondary characteristics, as long as it's really and truly an instance of [whatever item].

So, would you get an underripe orange at the market? An undersized one? A moldy one? If not, then you wouldn't [be willing to] get [just] "any" orange at the market :)

Due to the fact that both "any" and "one" are technically valid possibilities (although either would require a somewhat 'creative' interpretation of the test question prompt!), I think this is a good question for this site, regardless of the quality of the test itself. So, +1

We use any with plural countable nouns in negative sentences and most questions:

Will you get any oranges in the market?

If the noun was bread, which is uncountable, the solution could either be any or some:

Will you get any bread in the market?
Will you get some bread in the market?

In  requests, some is possible if we expect the answer to be ‘yes‘. Using any (= any + N + at all) suggests doubt or the speaker is exasperated with the listener, e.g. "Will you get any homework done?”
The obvious determiner that is missing in the OP's sentence would be an as in:

Will you get me an orange, please?

But seeing as that option is not given in the test, the next best solution must be "one" which we normally use with countable nouns.

Will you get one orange in the market?


Let me remark that one orange sounds strange in that sentence. You'd normally use an unless you had a reason to specify the number 1. So one orange is fine in Will you please get one orange in the market, but not in the OP's sentence, unless it's a request.

@PeterShor among the options only "one" can be selected. It's not ideal, I know, and I always prefer a "please" for requests but that's missing too.  "One" is slightly better than "Will you get any (= It doesn't matter which) orange in the market?" but neither sound very idiomatic.

one orange is fine but we'd usually say "a" for one. Do you have a car? rather than Do you have one car. The number one for items is usually for clarification. Oh, you do have a car? What about your family? We only have one car.

@Lambie If you read my answer, I said the best choice would be an orange but a/an is not included among the options.

The question is so bad. I don't know how those exam makers do it. :) I forgot to upvote but just did now.

@Lambie The question is grammatical and it is of higher level. Examiners ask such questions for A grade students.

@Lambie I agree that the test is terrible (not because it doesn't have a correct answer, but because it has two possible correct answers!), but the question is well written and OP does a great job of explaining exactly why he's confused and which answer options he's considering. Should we really be downvoting or closing questions like this on a site meant for learners, especially given OP's clarification that it's intended to be an advanced exam?

Fill in the blank: Will you get ____ orange in the market?
Correct answer: any. (You have to choose from the given options)
Context and Justification.
Consider the dialogue between a doctor and patient:
Doctor: "Drink water regularly. Orange juice is fine too.".
Patient: "Will I get any orange in the market?".
The patient's question is rhetorical, implying:
"You won't find oranges in the market, so your suggestion to drink orange juice isn't feasible."
The doctor understands this implication and offers an alternative.
Why "any" is correct
"Any" is used as a quantifier with singular countable nouns, indicating uncertainty or doubt.

As well as orange juice, it could also refer to orange paint, or anything that comes with the option of an orange colour.

"Will I get any orange in the market?". is an English mistake. \

@StuartF  The question lacks context, we don't know who is talking. We don't know if the "orange" refers to juice or any other item. The only clue lies with the words "a market" which is often associated with a street market in the open air. If the dialogue said a clothes shop, a supermarket or a paint shop then a more natural question would be in the form of a request:  "Please get any orange (t-shirt/pumpkin/cake/paint etc) one at the X store"
